# Multicast video captured via VLC shows a gray background for the first 1/2 second

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc

I am capturing multicast video using VLC.exe and performing some processing/converting using FFmpeg.exe. The resulting video starts with a gray background with some of the moving objects moving through the gray background. This seems to me that the video is not starting on an I-Frame, but on a B-Frame or a P-Frame. However, when I run ffprobe, it states the first frame is a key frame. After about 1/2 second, the video plays fine.

Here is the command I'm using to capture the video:

```
vlc.exe -I curses --run-time=10 "my.sdp" --sout=video.mp4
```

I'm not using anything special when I convert to an mp4 file using FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i video.mp4 -s 400x300 final.mp4
```

I tried to post an image of the first frame or two, but Stackoverflow gave me an error stating I need at least 10 reputation to post images. Sorry about that, an image would have helped.

I ran the command "ffprobe show_frames " and it looks like the first frame is a key frame. Of course I'm new to all this and I don't know what I'm doing or seeing.

Here is beginning of the output to the "ffprobe show_frames " command:

```
[FRAME]
media_type=video
key_frame=1
pkt_pts=0
pkt_pts_time=0.000000
pkt_dts=0
pkt_dts_time=0.000000
pkt_duration=1001
pkt_duration_time=0.033367
pkt_pos=48
pkt_size=756
width=400
height=300
pix_fmt=yuv420p
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
pict_type=I
coded_picture_number=0
display_picture_number=0
interlaced_frame=0
top_field_first=0
repeat_pict=0
reference=3
[/FRAME]
```

Is there any way to either tell VLC.exe to start capturing on an I-Frame (This would be the best solution as I specify a duration to capture the video) or is there a way to tell FFmpeg.exe to start converting the input video starting at the first I-Frame encountered?

Thanks,
-David

Comment: do you mean you want to confirm your frame is I-frame then only start capturing?

Comment: That would be the most ideal, yes. I need to get rid of the gray screen. I'm not sure why it is there, but my first guess is it has something to do the the P and B-Frames. If I could get rid of the gray background in the capture phase (VLC), that would be great. If I can get rid of it in the processing phase (FFmpeg) that would be at least better than having the gray screen.